# Magento 2 add to cart button text when added

Tags: magento2.3, addtocart

I want to change the add to cart button text, when a product is successfully added to the cart. I want to add soms custom html (a icon) to the button.

I tried to change the following, but that does not work. It does not read the HTMl but add it as plain text.

How can I solve this?

File: `/app/design/frontend/Theme/theme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('<i class="fad fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart');

    addToCartButton.removeClass(self.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
    addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextDefault);
    addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextDefault);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Answer posted check and let me know working or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to replace text() function to html() function

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart'); //add class fa fa-shopping-cart instead of fad fa-shopping-cart 

    addToCartButton.removeClass(self.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
    addToCartButton.find('span').html(addToCartButtonTextDefault); //replace text() funtion to html() function here
    addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextDefault);
}, 1000);
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did not saw that logic, quite easy :)

Comment: you are welcome bro